# Connection issues when connecting from java to salesforce via REST API

Tags: java, rest, salesforce

I am trying to connect to salesforce from my rest api. i perform both get and post request on salesforce standard objects. I am using the OAuth2.0 username password flow.
I get the access token every time before performing the exchange.
In order to reduce the no of calls i decided to put my get access token in a scheduler method.
So now, i have a scheduler which runs every 30 mins fetched the token and performs other computations.
But the problem arises when the next call is made to fetch the toekn i get I/O exception connection timed out.
What might be causing the program to fail in the second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the header grant_type=Refresh and not re-login 
here is a link on how to use it(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)

```
grant_type=refresh_token
client_id=<customerID>
client_secret=<your_Client_Secret>
refresh_token=<old_Token>

For Ex:
"POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=1955279925675241571&refresh_token=your token here"
```

Regards,

Comment: Since I am using OAuth2.0 Username-Password flow this is invalid as i never get refresh token, this works for web-server and user authentication flow as mentioned in the above document.